# Swift: Facebook Access Token is always returned even after removing App from Facebook settings

Tags: ios, swift, facebook, facebook-access-token

I'm using the Facebook SDK to login and progress through my app. When a user removes the app permissions from their Facebook page and then reopens the app, I want it to go to the very first view controller, which asks the user to log into Facebook. However, I'm running into the problem where the user is still able to access the app even after removing the permissions.

**So, how it should work:**

i) User goes to Facebook profile and removes app permissions from settings

ii) User completely closes down my app from iPhone.

iii) User reopens my app and the "Log into Facebook" view controller should appear.

**Instead, what happens:**

i) User goes to Facebook profile and removes app permissions from settings

ii) User completely closes down my app from iPhone.

iii) User reopens my app, and my app opens up in a different view controller that should only come up after user has logged in.

**AppDelegate.swift**

```
func application(_ application: UIApplication, didFinishLaunchingWithOptions launchOptions: [UIApplicationLaunchOptionsKey: Any]?) -> Bool {

    // Override point for customization after application launch.
    GMSServices.provideAPIKey("MY_API_KEY")
    GMSPlacesClient.provideAPIKey("MY_API_KEY")

    // FACEBOOK API STUFF

    FBSDKApplicationDelegate.sharedInstance().application(application, didFinishLaunchingWithOptions: launchOptions)
    print(FBSDKAccessToken.current())

    let storyboard = UIStoryboard(name: "Main", bundle: nil)
    self.window = UIWindow(frame: UIScreen.main.bounds)

    if(FBSDKAccessToken.current() != nil){

        print(FBSDKAccessToken.current())

        let initialViewController = storyboard.instantiateViewController(withIdentifier: "main")

        self.window?.rootViewController = initialViewController
        self.window?.makeKeyAndVisible()
    }
    else{

        print(FBSDKAccessToken.current())
        let initialViewController = storyboard.instantiateViewController(withIdentifier: "facebookLogin")

        self.window?.rootViewController = initialViewController
        self.window?.makeKeyAndVisible()
    }
    return true
}
```

Comment: remove app from device then check again.

Comment: Tried that, it works, but then when I go back to my Facebook account and delete the app from there, I still have the same problem.

Comment: yes it is not problem but you need logout your facebook session.

Comment: try this :[objLoginManager logOut];

Answer (score 1):

You need to logout your session manually

```
FBSDKLoginManager().logOut()
```

**OR**

```
FBSDKAccessToken.current = nil
FBSDKProfile.current = nil
```

Answer (score 1):

A solution is to refresh token every time your user start using the app when you delete your app from "Logged in with Facebook" you will receive error
"The operation couldn’t be completed. (com.facebook.sdk.core error 10.)"
so you can then sign out and make your user sign in once again

```
FBSDKAccessToken.refreshCurrentAccessToken { (_, _, error) in
            if error != nil {
                print(error!.localizedDescription)
                try! Auth.auth().signOut()
            }
        }
```